# HTMLの読み込み途中にsubmitすることによるパラメータの欠落はありえるか？

Tags: html, asp.net

ASP.NET WebForms（.NET2.0）でWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
そこそこ規模の大きなページで、formのsubmit（ポストバック）の発生する操作を素早く何度も繰り返すと、まれにformの最後にあるHiddenFieldコントロール（実体はinput[type=hidden]）の値が送信されないことがあります。
「送信されない」については、IEのF12デバッガのネットワークタブで、「要求本文」に確かにそのHiddenFieldのパラメータが含まれていないことを確認しました。
（もちろん通常はパラメータが含まれていることも確認済みです）

ここで仮説として、「submitの実行時点でまだレンダリングされていない要素があると、そこに含まれるパラメータは送信されない」という可能性を考えたのですが、これはありえますか？
それとも、「submitの実行は、そのform要素全体のレンダリングが完了するまで保留する」ようなHTMLの仕様が定義されていたりするため、ありえないのでしょうか？

Comment: レンダリング途中の送信を防ぐために、submitのトリガになってるボタンなどを非アクティブにしておいて、HTML最下部にjavascriptを仕込んで、その処理でトリガをアクティブにするような作りで試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: そうですね。もし欠落の原因がそれであれば、そのやり方が良いかなと思ってます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

あり得ます。
HTMLのソースコードがフォームの途中までしかクライアント側に到達してなくても、その時点でDOMが作られてレンダリングされてユーザは操作ができます。対処方法はいろいろあるかと思います。

- サーバ側のチェックで何とかする
- submitイベントを捕まえて全部揃っているかチェックする
- デフォルトで送信できないようにしておいて、</form>の直前か直後あたりに<script>を書いて送信できる状態にする

Comment: ありがとうございます。やっぱりそうなんですね。そうだとしたら、提示されている3つ目の案でいこうかなと思ってましたので、それでいこうと思います。

Answer (score 2):

ググっただけですが[ASP.NETのHiddenFieldの落とし穴](http://blog.livedoor.jp/tukuruyo/archives/52063806.html)というブログ記事を見つけました。ここに書かれているようにdisabled及びIEの挙動が影響していませんか？

Comment: 情報提供ありがとうございます。しかし、今回はC#でのEnabledも、JavaScriptでのdisabledも、制御していません。

Comment: 制御しているかどうかよりも、F12開発者ツールを使用されているのでしたら、disabledが設定されているかどうかを検索してみればはっきりしませんか？